# Compute Visual Profiler doesn't Fill the .csv files

Tags: cuda

Im trying to benchmark my CUDA application with **Compute Visual Profiler**. However the program is unable to fill any data in the .csv files. All the paths to CUDA are set properly in the profiler application.

After few runs on the exe file it returns the error:

> ```
> Error in Profiler data file
> 'C:/..../temp_compute_profiler_0_0.csv'
> at line number 1. No column found.
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible reasons... some of them to check for

- the execution time out. make sure that the profiler is not set to time out too soon
- the program doesn't finish executing (even if the kernel does). make sure there isn't a getchar at the end of your code
- try adding an explicit call to cudaThreadExit at the end of your code, and check for errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was actually using getchar to exit the program. After removing it the profiler works fine.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common reason for that kind of error is that your program never manages to launch a CUDA kernel or that it failed during its execution.